# How to display formatted text in jsp textarea from database when clicked?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Using JSP's `textarea` input field to give description to the task, the input field should reserve the formatting. So when saving to oracle database, I currently replace all new lines with html entities:

```
request.getParameter("DESCRIPTION").replace("\r\n", "& #13;& #10;"))
```

In this way, I'm displaying every description on the page, as a single line (retrieved from the database), I can see the HTML Entities written, but this way when clicked, the `textarea` input displays the text well formatted.

My problem is, that I don't want the HTML Entities to be seen, when displayed on the JSP page as a line, there is no need for formatting there, only when clicked, and the textarea field displays the description. Shall I transform them back, when retrieving from the db, with simply swapping the replace arguments?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your description string in the textArea is coming in a single line with HTML entities. So you want those HTML entities to be removed from the textArea and save the string to DB without any whitespace characters? Is that it?

Comment: It comes from a textarea, where the text is formatted. So I save the description into database, replacing every new line with html entity. And after submitting the formatted text, it's on the jsp page in a table, where you can see every description without formatting, so with the HTML Entities, but when clicked the textarea displays the description in a formatted way

Comment: and the problem is with the table view, because the textarea transforms the entities into new line, but in the table it is just a long line without new lines

Comment: Ok, so when you are displaying the long single lines on the jsp table, you must be iterating a list and showing it there. So can u make the table rows use a disabled text area with your text so that HTML entities dont show but once you click on the line, the editable text area anyways doesnt show the entities.

Comment: and what would be the attribute to set, to disable HTML entities? I can't find anything, but this solution sounds promising

Comment: You dont have to disable the HTML entities, as the text area will render the HTML entities but it will be disabled, so you in essence got a row with rendered HTML entities in a single line. When you click on it, you get your original text area which also renders the HTML entities. Sorry for being late on the reply, was doing something else :-)